# How to get the number of columns in a colspan/rowspan table header

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table header with two rows and several rowspans" and a colspans cells, like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Company</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Last Trade</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Trade Time</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Change</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Prev Close</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Open</th>
      <th colspan="3">Stuff</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bid</th>
      <th>Ask</th>
      <th>1y Target Est</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

This table thus has 9 columns, but it can be any random number. I need to loop through all columns once based on the cells in the table header, so I can assign header column ids as attributes to all cells below.

Is there an general way to do get a jquery selection containing the respective cell for each column?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles. You're doing it _frequent_ ly.

Comment: ok. I'm actually doing it all the time... why is it bad?

Comment: We already have an indexable, consistent tagging system. Arbitrary tags in titles are neither!

Comment: Thank you for your co-operation!

Comment: You need some sort of general algorithm that checks each cell in the header to see if it has a colspan attribute, and if it does (and it's greater than 1), check the next table row for a header cell instead. There's any number of ways to do this and I don't think either the browser or jQuery cares how it's done, so the onus is on you.

Comment: @mblase75 - ya, I was thinking along these lines now, too.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
$("tr").find("td").each(function() {
    // Manipulate results.
});
```

Comment: that won't work. If I use this with TH I will get 10 cells for 9 columns.